# RegExp para eliminar "[texto]" del final de una cadena

Tags: regex

tengo una cadena que me llega con diferentes mensajes al principio y una codificación compuesta por números y letras entre [] al final. Por ejemplo:

Por favor, revise su respuesta [B2]

Y me gustaría poder eliminar ese B2 usando expresiones regulares, ¿como lo hago?

Comment: Para futuras preguntas sobre regexes, es interesante que especifiques el lenguaje de programación o utilidad que utilizas

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con:

```
\s*\[[^]]*\]\s*$
```

**Explicado:**

```
\s*             # 0 o más espacios (spacios, tabuladores, saltos de línea...)
\[              # [ literal
     [^]] *     # Cualquier caracter que no sea ] repetido de 0 a más veces
\]              # ] literal
\s*             # 0 o más espacios
$               # Fin de string/línea
```

Comment: O también, desde el último `[` hasta el final de la línea? `.*\K\[.*$`

Comment: @abulafia, pues sí, también sería válido :-). Lo que como la pregunta no especifica lenguaje de programación/utilidad he preferido usar la respuesta de arriba. `\K` no es soportado por todos los lenguajes de programación o regexes. Javascript por nombrar alguno.